# Electron on windows 10

Tags: javascript

can anyone tell me how to instal electron on windows i try everything but nothing this steps i make sow far

1. install nodeJs
2. i update NodeJs and npm to the latest versions
3. i see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojX5yz35v4M) on youtube for guide but i have error when i make this comand on cmd

npm start

i want to ask if this is work on windows 10 if not i gona stop heare else how to instaled or how to make my fist electro app with javascrip - html5 - css

if there is alternative method to make apps with this 3 programming languages
and i want access the file system i want the user to can reade and write xml files

i try UWP apps with WinJS but i canot use require.js with the winJs i want this module feture with the modules and then i find the Electron 1.0 that can make apps with this 3 languages (javascript - html - css - and the js libs on the internt) i know the nodeJs have requre functions is like the modules on require.js and i dont have problem to lern NodeJs

1. what can i do to make Native app
2. to use file System (read and write xml file)
3. 3 languages javascript - html - css
4. i want the code on javascript to split like the require.js or NodeJs require function
5. i have windows 10

that is the criteria i have pls help me i stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
npm install electron -g
```

or

```
npm install electron --save-dev
```

as described [here](http://electron.atom.io/blog/2016/08/16/npm-install-electron)

after that go to the directory where your package.json via cmd and type `electron .`